# How do I make it so the circle doesn't go out of view? I'm using javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Here's my code that I currently have. I can get it so the ball moves, just need to make it so the ball doesn't go out of view. If I expand the scene I am still able to see the ball but it just gets harder and harder to view. I've tried doing an if else statement within the methods but I'm pretty sure I messed it up. So I stuck with my original code.

```
public class MovingCircle extends Application {

    private DrawCircle newCircle = new DrawCircle();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        //declare moving buttons
        Button left = new Button("Left");
        Button right = new Button("Right");
        Button up = new Button("Up");
        Button down = new Button("Down");

        //set buttons in horizonal row
        HBox box = new HBox(5);
        box.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        box.getChildren().add(up);
        box.getChildren().add(down);
        box.getChildren().add(left);
        box.getChildren().add(right);

        left.setOnAction(new LeftHandler());
        right.setOnAction(new RightHandler());
        up.setOnAction(new UpHandler());
        down.setOnAction(new DownHandler());

        //manage children
        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(newCircle);
        pane.setBottom(box);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(box, Pos.CENTER);

        //create the scene and place it in the stage
        Scene display = new Scene(pane, 350, 350);
        primaryStage.setScene(display);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    class LeftHandler implements EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
            newCircle.LeftButton();
        }
    }

    class RightHandler implements EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
            newCircle.RightButton();
        }
    }

    class UpHandler implements EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
            newCircle.UpButton();
        }
    }

    class DownHandler implements EventHandler<javafx.event.ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) {
            newCircle.DownButton();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    class DrawCircle extends StackPane {

        private Circle movingCircle = new Circle(50.0);

        public DrawCircle() {
            getChildren().add(movingCircle);
            movingCircle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            movingCircle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        }

        public void UpButton() {
            movingCircle.setTranslateY(movingCircle.getTranslateY() - 15);
        }

        public void DownButton() {
            movingCircle.setTranslateY(movingCircle.getTranslateY() + 15);
        }

        public void LeftButton() {
            movingCircle.setTranslateX(movingCircle.getTranslateX() - 15);
        }

        public void RightButton() {
            movingCircle.setTranslateX(movingCircle.getTranslateX() + 15);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: " I've tried doing an if else statement within the methods". What happened when you did this? All you have to do is not move the circle if it takes it out of the range of the containing pane. Off-topic, but your `DrawCircle` class seems completely redundant. Why not just use a `Circle`, without the `StackPane`, and have a method to move a circle? Subclassing JavaFX `Node` (including layout) classes is usually the wrong approach.

Comment: It would underline some of my code in the “if” code block, but I wasn’t sure how to fix it. And I can change it! I’m new to JavaFX  so I’m kind of just getting the end result currently. So what your saying is create a Circle node instead of using StackPane and a method to move the circle?

Comment: Well, I don't see the point in your `DrawCircle` class at all. Just use a Circle. But that's not really relevant; all you need to do is write an `if`-`else` that makes sure you don't move the circle if it would go out of bounds of the pane. If you have syntax errors, read the error message and fix them.

Comment: The if - else would go in my movement methods correct?